# Give read write-only access to specific folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, rhel, chmod

I created an LDAP group rcars. I also created a directory rcars. How can I set permission so that only rcars group can read/write?

Comment: Does your system use LDAP for its group memberships? Have you looked at the `chmod` and `chgrp` commands?

Comment: yes it uses LDAP. I have tried both chmod & chgrp as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rcars` directory will first need to be part of `rcars` group (the folder's owner or root can perform this operation).

Syntax: `chgrp <groupName> -R <folderName>`

```
 chgrp rcars -R rcars
```

Then, the `rcars` group will need `rw` permissions of the directory.

Syntax:`chmod g+rw <folderName>`

```
 chmod g+rw -R rcars
```

To remove others access:

```
chmod o-rw -R rcars
```

- `-R` is for recursive permission (all sub-directories and files in it).

Comment: Thank you. The group was changed to rcars. However the perms still remain drwxrwsr-x

Comment: @MervynClarke try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I also did the same for the user. chmod u-rw -R rcars. Thanks again.